# execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, triggercontext, queryexception

I have a trigger in place for Opportunity. This trigger is meant to fire when an opportunity reaches the 'VoB Pending' stage.

```
trigger opportunityOwnerAlert on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {
Id[] oppList = new List<Id>();
    if(trigger.isBefore && (trigger.IsInsert || trigger.IsUpdate) && lightningStep.isFirstTime){
        lightningStep.isFirstTime = false; //prevents recursion
        for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
            if(opp.stagename == 'VoB Pending' && opp.Push_To_Lightning_Step__c == True){
                    oppList.add(opp.Id);
            }
        }
    }
     if(!oppList.isEmpty()) {
             lightningStep.Sendtest(oppList);
        }

}
```

The only time it fails is when I create an opportunity and set the stage to 'VoB Pending', soon as i hit the create button (Save), i get the folowing error.

*opportunityOwnerAlert: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject Class.lightningStep.Sendtest: line 10, column 1 Trigger.opportunityOwnerAlert: line 12, column 1*

line 10 is just a soql query,

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = : oppIds LIMIT 1];
```

Im a little lost as to why its not being picked up by the trigger since i have the 'before insert' on the trigger. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `Id` of a SObject is not available in `BeforeInsert` context. As this is running before the records are there in database.

Hence firing this

`[SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = : oppIds LIMIT 1];`

will return an empty List and when you try to store the return value into `Opportunity opp`, Salesforce tries to internally fetch the first item from list and store it in `opp`.

But as list is empty, hence you see an exception `List has no rows for assignment to SObject`

I am not aware of full use case, but you can try shifting your context to `AfterInsert`.

BTW, why to just query Id again, if you already have an `Id` from the trigger.